# How to fix line to line spacing error in Allegro?

Tags: pcb, orcad, allegro

[image]

I have a line to line spacing error in Allegro. I don't know how to fix it. If I make the width of the trace smaller, it gives me a line to width error. And I also don't understand Why I get this error. It doesn't look like the lines are touching, and I think they have enough clearance between them.

Comment: You should highlight in your picture where the error is located. Also you should check that you do not have specific constraints attached to the subject traces that are different from your defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Your spacing constraints are being violated probably by that unconnected trace in the bottom left.  Could also be the little jog you have at the end of it.    Go into constraints, physical and see what your spacing is, if those traces are the same net make sure you check same net spacing.

For more clarity you can turn on drc layer under visibility.  Also if you're really stuck turn on drc layers, and all copper layers.  Run drc report then Zoom way in somewhere.  Now click on coordinates and it will take you right to the problem.

Make sure it's not on some layer that's not visible too

Comment: That bottom left part is part of the copper pour that I laid out as the ground plane.

Comment: Look at where your DRC markers are in that picture, it could be caused by how close the lines are because of the footprint.  Try as an experiment shrinking their width and I bet it goes away.  Again this is driven by your constraints settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to your line to line spacing value. Open constraints manager and change the minimum line-to-line spacing to an acceptable value (I prefer 8 mils generally). If the problem still occurs, you can leave a commennt to identify your problem. (the version is 16.5 I suppose)

Comment: I'm going to be milling out this board on a board router and the minimum size end mill that I can use is 10 mils. So that means the minimum line-to-line spacing should be 10 mils, right? And yes this is version 16.5.

Comment: If 10 mils is without a tolerance, try to use a bit greater value (12 or 15) to make sure that every details is OK. However, what I was trying to say is that if the minimum line-to-line spacing value denoted in the constraint manager sub-menu is greater than the space that you are drawing, you get error messages. For example, let the spacing value in the CM be 10 mils. If you route 2 lines with 8 mils spacing between them, that L-L marker may occur. In short, YES, your l-l spacing should be 10 mils:)